# How Angular routes URLs like api?id=1&id=2?

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I am new to ng-route. I have a site called www.foo.com. And I just want to assign the template HTML (fooapi.view.html) and the controller (fooapi.controller.js) to the URLs like

> www.foo.com/api?id=1&id=2&id=3

. I wonder if somebody could give some suggestion.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you will need to install ng-route. To do so, you can either use npm or bower for the installation, or a manual way by downloading ng-route javascript file which can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route)

To install using bower

```
bower install angular-route
```

To install using npm

```
npm install angular-route
```

After, completing those steps, include the file named angular-route.min.js to your index.html, depending on where you have installed the downloaded files.

```
<script src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
```

After doing so, include 'ngRoute' to you angular's module

```
angular.module('ngApp', ['ngRoute'])
```

Now you will have to create a angular's config module

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/foo/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'fooapi.view.html'
        controller: 'FooCtrl'
    });
})
```

In your fooapi.controller.js

```
.controller('FooCtrl', function ($routeParams) {
     //getting the id from the URL
     console.log($routeParams.id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! I just have a quick question - I actually have quite a few similar APIs under the same page such as (1) www.foo.com/api01?id=1&id=2&id=3; (2) www.foo.com/api02?id=1&id=2 to call. Is it possible to assign different templates and controllers with your method?

Comment: api01 and api02 are two different links right? You can do that by creating another route in the config for that Url and link it with that different template and controller.